# Counting how many times a value occurs in multi-level array of nested objects

Tags: javascript, json, loops, object

So I've got an array objects that contains the `startDate`, `endDate` and an array of student objects which contains the student's `fullName`, `docId` and `attendanceStatus` for a course for a class. I'm not allowed to change the way the data is structured.

```
[
   {
     startDate: Mon Jul 26 2021 08:19:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time),
     endDate: Mon Jul 26 2021 09:19:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time),
     id: "EE201_433",
     title: "EE201",
     students: [
      {docId: "LKfpyWyWuXlbBLUBoRp2", attendanceStatus: "Present", fullName: "John Smith"},
      {docId: "nwHWP3iNjGm2tEODsaLo", attendanceStatus: "Absent", fullName: "Claire Smith"},
      {docId: "x9TLXbsVfgpZfQU7aj8Z", attendanceStatus: "Excused", fullName: "Jane Smith"}
     ]
   },
   {
     startDate: Mon Jul 19 2021 08:19:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time),
     endDate: Mon Jul 19 2021 09:19:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time),
     id: "EE201_432",
     title: "EE201",
     students: [
      {docId: "LKfpyWyWuXlbBLUBoRp2", attendanceStatus: "Absent", fullName: "John Smith"},
      {docId: "nwHWP3iNjGm2tEODsaLo", attendanceStatus: "Present", fullName: "Claire Smith"},
      {docId: "x9TLXbsVfgpZfQU7aj8Z", attendanceStatus: "Excused", fullName: "Jane Smith"}
     ]
   }
]
```

How can I create a function that takes the student's `docId` as an argument then returns something like this. How can I count how many times a student is absent, present or excused?

```
{
 LKfpyWyWuXlbBLUBoRp2: {present: 1, absent: 1, excused: 0},
}
```

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way to do this but this works

```js
const courses = [
   {
     startDate: "Mon Jul 26 2021 08:19:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)",
     endDate: "Mon Jul 26 2021 09:19:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)",
     id: "EE201_433",
     title: "EE201",
     students: [
      {docId: "LKfpyWyWuXlbBLUBoRp2", attendanceStatus: "Present", fullName: "John Smith"},
      {docId: "nwHWP3iNjGm2tEODsaLo", attendanceStatus: "Absent", fullName: "Claire Smith"},
      {docId: "x9TLXbsVfgpZfQU7aj8Z", attendanceStatus: "Excused", fullName: "Jane Smith"}
     ]
   },
   {
     startDate: "Mon Jul 19 2021 08:19:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)",
     endDate: "Mon Jul 19 2021 09:19:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)",
     id: "EE201_432",
     title: "EE201",
     students: [
      {docId: "LKfpyWyWuXlbBLUBoRp2", attendanceStatus: "Absent", fullName: "John Smith"},
      {docId: "nwHWP3iNjGm2tEODsaLo", attendanceStatus: "Present", fullName: "Claire Smith"},
      {docId: "x9TLXbsVfgpZfQU7aj8Z", attendanceStatus: "Excused", fullName: "Jane Smith"}
     ]
   },
]

const id = "LKfpyWyWuXlbBLUBoRp2";
const getStudentAttendance = (id) => {
  let student = {
    absent: 0,
    present: 0,
    excused: 0
  }
  
  courses.forEach(course => {
      const { attendanceStatus } = course.students.find(({ docId }) => docId === id)
      if (attendanceStatus) {
          student[attendanceStatus.toLowerCase()] += 1
      }
  })
  
  return {
      [id]: student
  }
}

console.log(getStudentAttendance(id))
```

Comment: Hi, this solution answers the original question posted by the OP but not the edited one (a function returning the data o a single student, given the ID). Anyway, it is recommended not to answer questions that do not meet the community standards in terms of quality or do not show any effort to find the solution (see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/))

Comment: @secan Ok I've edited the code so that it now answers the edited question. If it is not recommended I will avoid answering these kinds of questions in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', () => {

  const data = [
      {
          startDate: "Mon Jul 26 2021 08:19:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)",
          endDate: "Mon Jul 26 2021 09:19:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)",
          id: "EE201_433",
          title: "EE201",
          students: [
          {docId: "LKfpyWyWuXlbBLUBoRp2", attendanceStatus: "Present", fullName: "John Smith"},
          {docId: "nwHWP3iNjGm2tEODsaLo", attendanceStatus: "Absent", fullName: "Claire Smith"},
          {docId: "x9TLXbsVfgpZfQU7aj8Z", attendanceStatus: "Excused", fullName: "Jane Smith"}
          ]
      },
      {
          startDate: "Mon Jul 19 2021 08:19:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)",
          endDate: "Mon Jul 19 2021 09:19:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)",
          id: "EE201_432",
          title: "EE201",
          students: [
          {docId: "LKfpyWyWuXlbBLUBoRp2", attendanceStatus: "Absent", fullName: "John Smith"},
          {docId: "nwHWP3iNjGm2tEODsaLo", attendanceStatus: "Present", fullName: "Claire Smith"},
          {docId: "x9TLXbsVfgpZfQU7aj8Z", attendanceStatus: "Excused", fullName: "Jane Smith"}
          ]
      },
  ]

  var present = 0;
  var absent = 0;
  var excused = 0;
  var id = document.getElementById('id').value;

  for (var A = 0; A < data.length; A++){
      for(var B = 0; B < data[A].students.length; B++){

          var attendance = data[A].students[B].attendanceStatus

          if(data[A].students[B].docId == id){
          
              if(attendance == 'Present'){present++}
              else if(attendance == 'Absent'){absent++}
              else{excused++}
              
          }
      }
  }

  var node = document.createElement("LI");
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(id + ': ' + ' present: ' + present + ', absent: ' + absent +  ', excused: ' + excused);
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(node);

})
```

```html
<label>Enter ID</label>
<input id="id">
<button id="btn">Get attendance</button>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```